# While loop crashes inconsistently when generating random numbers with constraint

Tags: python, numpy, random, while-loop, crash

1. Start with a vector, vector0
2. Initialize a while loop that generates another random vector, vector1
3. Use the dot product to calculate the angle between them
4. If the angle theta between vector0 and vector1 is too large, keep re-making vector1 until it's small enough

It looks something like this:

```
# initialize the angle
theta = 0
# the first vector:
vector0 = [x0, y0, z0]
# initialize while loop:
while theta <= 0 or theta > np.pi/8:
    # create the second vector using random numbers
    x1 = random.uniform(-maxlen, maxlen)
    y1 = random.uniform(-maxlen, maxlen)
    z1 = random.uniform(-maxlen, maxlen)
    vector1 = [x1, y1, z1]
    # find the angle between the two vectors. The loop will start again if it is too large.
    theta = np.arccos(np.dot(vector0, vector1) / np.linalg.norm(vector0)*np.linalg.norm(vector1)
```

This process is nested within two other loops - not especially large ones, only 5 step & 100 step. A simple enough process, I thought.

Here is my problem: this while loop crashes about 70% of the time. Just gives up. But some of the time, it works perfectly!

It's easy to kill it and re-initialize but sometimes I'm doing this ten times over to get the code to run through successfully, which is becoming unbearable.

Am I doing something daft that is causing this?
Perhaps there's a bug that sometimes triggers in my code, or I've made a mathematical error?
Maybe there is a more memory/CPU-efficient way to achieve this outcome?
Or do I just need to use a more powerful machine?

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of a case where the loop crashes deterministically?

Comment: why not just generate a vector by first generating the angle between your vector and the new vector from a uniform distribution in [minimal angle, maximal angle] and then generating the angle of rotation on the plain normal to the original vector from a uniform distribution in [0, 2*pi]?

Comment: In your definition of theta, beware the (lack of) parentheses in the denominator. In Python, `24/3*4` evaluates to 32, and `24/(3*4)` evaluates to 2. You probably want the second value. If you get your normalized dot product wrong, possibly above 1, then `arccos` will crash. Try to print out the intermediate values for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method for generating a random vector without needing to check if it's within the required angle:

```
import numpy as np
import math

max_phi = np.pi/8

v1 = np.array([1, 1, 1])
phi = np.random.rand()*max_phi
psi = np.random.rand()*2*np.pi

# rotate v1 in the plane created by v1 and [0, 0, 1]
# unless v1 is parallel to [0, 0, 1], then use the plane normal to [1, 0, 0]
if (v1/np.sum(v1**2)**0.5).T @ np.array([0, 0, 1]) == 1:
    axis = np.array([1, 0, 0])
else:
    axis = np.cross(v1, np.array([0, 0, 1]))

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])

# find the rotation matrix about the 'axis' axis
R0 = rotation_matrix(axis, phi)
# find the rotation matrix about the v1
R1 = rotation_matrix(v1  , psi)
# apply random rotations to create a random vector withing an angle of phi 
# radians from v1
v2 = R1@R0@v1
```

Note that the distribution of the random vector will be different. Vectors that are closer to the original vector will have higher probabilities of being generated.